# Custom ASP.NET MVC cache controllers in a shared hosting environment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, full-trust

I'm using custom controllers that cache static resources (CSS, JS, etc.) and images. I'm currently working with a hosting provider that has set me up under a full trust profile. Despite being in full trust, my controllers fail because the caching strategy relies on the File class to directly open a resource file prior to treatment and storage in memory.

Is this something that would likely occur in all full trust shared hosting environments or is this specific to my host? The static files live within my application's structure and not in an arbitrary server path. It seems to me that custom caching would require code to access the file directly, and am hoping someone else has dealt with this issue.

Comment: what's the exception you're getting?

Comment: A SecurityException on the File.ReadAllText method, or alternatives I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to do this you need to impersonate the IIS user to gain file system access. If you can't do this in a shared hosting environment, then you need to change service providers (we moved to EC2).